# Pivot Result Creation from SQL query using two tables and join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my first table like this, it contains platform and their platform code

```
+-----------+------+
| platforms | code |  
+-----------+------+
| java      | 1    |  
| .net      | 2    |  
| perl      | 3    |
+-----------+------+
```

My second table contains columns as shown below.

```
+-------+------+------+------+
| pname | code | year | deve |
+-------+------+------+------+
| a     | 1    | 2018 | abia |
| b     | 1    | 2017 | arun |
| c     | 2    | 2018 | abia |
| d     | 3    | 2017 | arun |
| e     | 2    | 2017 | arun |
| f     | 3    | 2018 | abia |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

Result expected in Pivot Format like this:

```
+-----+-------+------+------+------+
| year| deve  | .net | java | perl |
+-----+-------+------+------+------+
| 2018| abia  | 1    | 1    |  1   |
| 2017| arun  | 1    | 1    |  1   |
+-----+-------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; this sort of posting would be better suited to one of those freelancer hiring sites; it's more like a job spec/"do my work for me" request than a "I need to do this and here's what I've tried, here's what I'm stuck with, can anyone help me out?"

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve your goal? Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, so please do share your attempts and explain why they didn't work; either due to an error or unexpected results. If you haven't already tried, I suggest doing so first, and then posting your attempt if you fail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Pivot Script which meets your expectation

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE
(platforms VARCHAR(20), code   INT)
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT 'java', 1 UNION ALL  
SELECT '.net', 2 UNION ALL  
SELECT 'perl', 3   

DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE
(pname  VARCHAR(20), code INT,[year] INT,  deve  VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT 'a',1,2018,'abia' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'b',1,2017,'arun' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'c',2,2018,'abia' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'd',3,2017,'arun' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'e',2,2017,'arun' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'f',3,2018,'abia'  

SELECT [year],deve,MAX([java]) AS [java],MAX([.net]) AS [.net],MAX([perl] ) AS [perl]
FROM
(
SELECT platforms,CASE WHEN pname IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NUll END AS pname ,A.code ,deve,[year]  FROM  @Table2 A
INNER JOIN @Table  B 
ON A.code=b.code
)
AS SRC
PIVOT
(
MAX(pname) FOR platforms IN( [java],[.net],[perl] )
) AS PVT
GROUP BY [year],deve
```

Result

```
year    deve    java    .net    perl
------------------------------------
2018    abia      1      1       1
2017    arun      1      1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Pivot using dynamic sql approach as it fits when the columns to be added dynamically to get the specific result

```
CREATE TABLE #Table 
(platforms VARCHAR(20), code   INT)
INSERT INTO #Table
SELECT 'java', 1 UNION ALL  
SELECT '.net', 2 UNION ALL  
SELECT 'perl', 3   

CREATE TABLE #Table2
(pname  VARCHAR(20), code INT,[year] INT,  deve  VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #Table2
SELECT 'a',1,2018,'abia' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'b',1,2017,'arun' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'c',2,2018,'abia' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'd',3,2017,'arun' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'e',2,2017,'arun' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'f',3,2018,'abia'  


DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(max),
        @IsnullColumns nvarchar(max),
        @Sql  nvarchar(max)


SELECT @Columns= STUFF((SELECT ', '+QUOTENAME(platforms)   FROM #Table FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
SELECT @IsnullColumns=STUFF((SELECT ', '+'MAX('+QUOTENAME(platforms)+') AS ' +QUOTENAME(platforms)  FROM #Table FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql='
SELECT[year],deve, '+@IsnullColumns+'
FROM
(   SELECT platforms,
            CASE WHEN pname IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NUll END AS pname ,A.code ,deve,[year]  
    FROM  #Table2 A
    INNER JOIN #Table  B 
    ON A.code=b.code
) AS SRC
 PIVOT 
   (MAX(pname) FOR platforms IN('+@Columns+')
   ) AS PVT
GROUP BY [year],deve'
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result

```
year    deve    java    .net    perl
------------------------------------
2018    abia      1      1       1
2017    arun      1      1       1
```